# Run mysql command from java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql" -u root -padmin < C:\script.sql > C:\redir.txt
```

by using this java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

where command is a string containing mysql command. If I use the command from a cmd, it works perfectly, but if I run the java line, it doesn't create the redir.txt with the result of the query. I can't figure out why it doesn't work (by the way, it doesn't throw any exception or error message of any kind).

Comment: exec() has a whole load of idiosyncracies that make it far from straightforward to use.  This is a very useful article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html .  However, I'd also post your code.

Comment: Why? It runs as a service. It is designed to run as a service. What exactly is the point of creating yet another way to start it?

Answer (score 1):

Put the command in a batch file/bash script (depending on your environment) and call that using `exec()`.  Java's exec() has lots of problems especially where command-line parameters are concerned, so this is usually the best way to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Various problems, starting here:

```
< C:\script.sql
```

respectively there.

```
> C:\redir.txt
```

Those "redirects" simply don't work from within commands that you sent from Java. Meaning: those "<" and ">" are dealt with by the cmd.shell.

It **might** be possible to create a command like

```
cmd.exe ....
```

that works with those pipes; but I am not sure. What will definitely work:

- use a process builder and acquire the stdin input of the sub process; and its stdout/stderr output streams
- write Java code that **writes** the content of script.sql into that stdin stream and that **reads** from the stdout stream, for example to push that into the redir.txt outfile

And finally: you have to **escape** the single `\` to `\\` within the string literals in your command!